# Why this example of fpinscala works?(no argument name)

Tags: scala, functional-programming

all:
I'm a newbie to scala. I'm not quite understanding an example of curry in the book "functional programming in scala".
Why a function without variables like a, b can be compiled and run smoothly?

```
def curry[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) =
  a => b => f(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala `parameterName => body` is an anonymous function that takes a parameter named `parameterName` and whose body is `body`.

So `a => b => f(a,b)` is a function with the parameter `a` and the body `b => f(a,b)`, which is itself a function with the parameter `b` and the body `f(a,b)`. In that body `a` and `b` are defined because they're parameters.

If that makes it less confusing for you, we can rewrite this using named functions instead:

```
def curry[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) = {
  def f1(a: A) = {
    def f2(b: B) = f(a,b)
    f2
  }
  f1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because

```
a => b => f(a, b)
```

is anonymous function (lambda). a and b are variables without any value at the time. They are used only to construct the function (note that curry function return type is another function)